# Get the buyer's e-mail and order id after making a purchase in Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout

I've been reading the documentation for the second day and I can't find how to get at least some data about the order. After the session is created, there is a redirect to the payment page and a return to the "Thank You" page, but there is no data in the superglobal variables. How do I get the buyer's e-mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a checkout session, we save its ID somewhere in a cookie and after returning to the store page, we get everything we need from there. Figured it out)